# how to add checkbox in field settings form in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

[image]

How Can I add custom check box under the default value fieldset and below the text field and it's custom submit handler?

I have used hook_form_field_ui_field_edit_form_alter() but it's not works.
I have used hook_field_widget_third_party_settings_form() but it's not working.

Don't know what I am doing wrong. 
Please help.

Comment: What do you want the checkbox for? What should it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the form in the below mentioned way

```
function {your_module}_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'field_config_edit_form':
      $form['default_value']['widget'][1] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title' => t('Your checkbox'),
        '#size' => 10,
        '#maxlength' => 255,
        '#default_value' => 1,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#description' => '<p>' . t('Your checkbox altered.') . '</p>',
    );
    break;
  }
}
```

I have tried in my local attaching the screenshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help!
If I want it for multiple field types like (number, 'taxonomy', 'list', 'text' etc) then it's default behavior is different for D8
while in D7 when we use hook_form_field_ui_field_edit_form_alter() , we can pass it simply as an array. like:

```
if (in_array($form['#field']['module'], array('number', 'taxonomy', 'list', 'text'))) {
    //My form field here
}
```

But in D8 there are some new term like: entity_autocomplete, 'select' (instead of 'list') etc.
So in this case I think hook_form_alter will not work for all type of fileds.
that's why my approach was 
hook_form_field_ui_field_edit_form_alter OR hook_field_widget_third_party_settings_form.